# Visual Studio 2019 and Git Update View Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a ASP.Net MVC 5 application using Visual Studio 2019. I also am using Git and GitHub with this project (first time - previously I have used TortoiseSVN).

I've noticed that when I make a change to a Razor View, a red tick will appear beside the file in Visual Studio to signify that something has changed within the View.

[image]

However, I can only see the changes I've made within the View if I stop debugging, and then restart. Normally I could make a change to the Razor View whilst debugging, e.g. a text change, Save the Razor View within Visual Studio, and then F5 or Ctrl F5 within the browser and the page with refresh with the latest text change.

For some reason I believe this is related to Git because I have other MVC 5 applications on my laptop within the same folder structure which are not using Git, and this problem does not exist.

Surely I don't have to stop debugging and restart every time I want to see a change to a View?

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: The red tick is indeed for files that are version controlled. But except if you're facing an improbable bug, Git is not the cause of this behavior...

Comment: @Philippe I pulled project files down to my personal laptop from GitHub and I can't create the same problems on my personal laptop when I run the project. It looks like it is something to do with my work laptop, but again, it only happens with this project which is version controlled by Git, and not with other MVC apps which do not use any Version Control. Confused!

Comment: You could try to copy the files elsewhere and open the project to see if you reproduce outside a git repository. That way you could have part of the answer.

Comment: Or temporary move the '.git' folder.